# Disabling ASLR in Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: c, macos, security, osx-snow-leopard, aslr

Essentially I want to disable ASLR in Mac OS X Snow Leopard and use gcc todo some buffer overflowing and stack overflows. Anyone know how to disable ASLR?

Comment: I was going to say google it, but google just turns up your question. :(

Comment: The aslr is kernel technology which needs only `PIE` code generation from gcc. Buffer overflow and stack overflow protection is wider than just ASLR.

Answer (score 3):

Asan authors listed several ways to disable ASLR in MacOS: https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/issues/detail?id=29

For 10.6

```
export DYLD_NO_PIE=1
```

For 10.7 and newer:

- "unset the MH_PIE bit in an already linked executable" with `--no-pie` flag of the script

  http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/build/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py?view=markup
- or link the program with --no_pie flag.

And there is also hard method used by gdb: http://reverse.put.as/2011/08/11/how-gdb-disables-aslr-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable "DYLD_NO_PIE".  See "man dyld".  This works on OS X 10.6 but not on 10.5.