# Documented way to disable ASLR on OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, aslr

On OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), it's possible to disable [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) for a single process if you launch the process by calling [`posix_spawn()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html) and passing the undocumented attribute `0x100`. Like this:

```c
extern char **environ;
pid_t pid;
posix_spawnattr_t attr;

posix_spawnattr_init(&attr);
posix_spawnattr_setflags(&attr, 0x100);
posix_spawn(&pid, argv[0], NULL, &attr, argv, environ);
```

(This is reverse-engineered from [Apple's GDB sources](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c).)

The trouble with undocumented features like this is that they tend to disappear without notice. According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001746/68063) the dynamic linker [`dyld`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) used to consult the environment variable `DYLD_NO_PIE`, but this does not work in 10.9; similarly the static linker apparently used to take a `--no-pie` option, but this is no longer the case.

So is there a documented way to disable ASLR?

(The reason why I need to disable ASLR is to ensure repeatability, when testing and debugging, of code whose behaviour depends on the addresses of objects, for example address-based hash tables and [BIBOP-based](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/b.html#term-bibop) memory managers.)

Comment: No it is not something that would likely be documented.

Comment: @uchuugaka: On what basis you do say that?

Comment: Certainly seems like something not intended to be overridden. That's why it would be undocumented. What are you trying to do that you need this?

Comment: @uchuugaka: See revised post.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Actually, there still is a `-no_pie` linker flag, but you might have thought it is actually called `--no-pie`.

Lets have a small test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const char *test = "test";

int main() {
  printf("%p\n", (void*)test);
  return 0;
}
```

And compile as usual first:

```
cc -o test-pie test-pie.c
```

And check the flags

```
$ otool -hv test-pie
test-pie:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL LIB64     EXECUTE    16       1376   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
```

Alright there is a `PIE` flag in there, let's verify

```
$ for x in $(seq 1 5); do echo -n "$x "; ./test-pie; done
1 0x10a447f96
2 0x10e3cbf96
3 0x1005daf96
4 0x10df50f96
5 0x104e63f96
```

That looks random enough.

Now, lets tell the linker we don't want `PIE` using `-Wl,-no_pie`:

```
cc -o test-nopie test-pie.c -Wl,-no_pie
```

Sure enough the `PIE` flag is gone:

```
$ otool -hv test-nopie
test-pie:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL LIB64     EXECUTE    16       1376   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL
```

And test:

```
$ for x in $(seq 1 5); do echo -n "$x "; ./test-nopie; done
1 0x100000f96
2 0x100000f96
3 0x100000f96
4 0x100000f96
5 0x100000f96
```

So we make the linker not add the `PIE` flag, and my Mavericks system seems to still abide by it.

FWIW, the `PIE` flag is defined and documented in `/usr/include/mach-o/loader.h` as `MH_PIE`.

There are tools all over the Internet to clear the PIE flag from existing binaries, e.g. [http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/build/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906073648/http://src.chromium.org:80/svn/trunk/src/build/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py)

While I cannot offer you a documented way to start a `PIE`-flagged binary without ASLR, since you want to test code, presumably your own, just linking your test programs with `-no_pie` or removing the `PIE` flag afterwards from your test binaries should suffice?

Comment: `change_mach_o_flags.py` set `MH_NO_HEAP_EXECUTION` bit by default. If you do want to change the PIE flag only, use `python change_mach_o_flags.py --executable-heap --no-pie <path_to_mach_o>`