# How debugger managed to disable ASLR

Tags: linux, gdb, aslr

I have wrote a c program on a Linux computer which displays `main` function address.
ASLR seems to be enabled because address is not the same if a launch the program several times.

I have tried to debug this program with gdb. When the program is run through gdb, the main function's address is the same.

So it seems gdb is able to disable ASLR. How gdb does that ?

Comment: I suppose the same way as here https://stackoverflow.com/q/5194666/72178.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, this is done using the [personality](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) library call.  The GDB code that does this can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/nat/linux-personality.c#l31).

On MacOS, this is done using a flag set in the `posix_spawnattr_t` passed to [posix_spawn](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html), the code that does this can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/darwin-nat.c#l1807).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the equivalent for macOS?

Comment: I don't sorry.  I don't think GDB has support for disabling randomization on MacOS.

Comment: @Bob5421 On Linux, you can control whether GDB enables / disables ASLR with `set disable-randomization on/off`.

Comment: On macOS, GDB disables ASLR by using an undocumented flag in posix_spawn, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897963/2554472).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for the pointer.  I've extended the answer with a link to the GDB code that does this for MacOS.