# How to search for strings and other data in the memory of a running process?

Tags: macos, memory, heap-memory, hexdump, hex-editors

This is on mac, so there's no /proc/mem.    I've seen tools on windows to attach to a running proc and allow you to search the raw memory.    Can't find that on mac.

maybe somehow with gdb or Xcode?

Comment: I do not suspect that this will be easy. If it is, I'd be afraid.

Comment: This is a similar thread about using C to the memory of a running process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668/reading-other-process-memory-in-os-x